# Keyboard buttons like "Enter", "Space" and "Backspace" are suppressed

Tags: jquery, fancybox

In fancybox container I've loaded the form with textarea field and some input fields in it. The input controls and textarea are working, but when I press Enter or Space or Backspace on my keyboard, nothing happens.

I've made an assumption that FancyBox intercepts the pressing of these keys and prevents any further action on them. Can I block or bypass this effect or the only way is to downgrade the FancyBox to version 1.3.4?

Answer (score 3):

Fancybox v.2.x intercepts these keys for navigation and closing

```
keys: {
next: [13, 32, 34, 39, 40], // enter, space, page down, right arrow, down arrow
prev: [8, 33, 37, 38], // backspace, page up, left arrow, up arrow
close: [27] // escape key
}
```

however it ignores key events within form elements

```
if (keys) {
D.bind('keydown.fb', function (e) {
// Ignore key events within form elements
if ($.inArray(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase(), ['input', 'textarea', 'select', 'button']) > -1) {    return; }
....
```

(from line 395 of the fancybox js file).
What version of Fancybox are you using?

## **UPDATE**:

Just tested a form with Fancybox v2.0.3 and I can use backspace, space and enter with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've experienced this problem before. However, for me it was with the arrow keys. I don't think I had problems with the keys you mentioned but maybe I was using a very old version of fancybox.

I was able to find the solution to my problem here:
http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/b3c617631c465424?pli=1

It requires modifications to the fancybox javascript file.